# What is the checking(this) passing and means?

Tags: javascript

[image: What is the checking(this) passing and means?]

What is the checking(this) passing and means? Any help will be appreciated. I still have problem in posting the code so i just screenshot my code. Thank you.

Comment: an advice, pls don't post code contained in images.

Comment: “I still have problem in posting the code” — does copy and paste not work on your computer?

Comment: Yes, i already put in Ctrl + K but still not working... T_T

Comment: @wskstack: well, maybe you could work on getting copy and paste working on your computer before you chuck screenshots of your code at us?

Answer (score 2):

`checking(this)` means passing the instance of the element on which the event is defined. So if you say

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" onclick="foo(this);"/>
```

You are passing the textbox instance to the onclick function foo.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the current element (in your case, one of those two `<input>` elements). You're calling `checking` with the element that you clicked on as the first argument.

Comment: Is that mean the checking(this) is passing the value male/female?

Comment: @wskstack: No, you're passing the whole element. This is covered in just about any JavaScript tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `onclick` the `checking` function will fire, and `this` which is the element will be passed to the function.

**THIS =**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female" onClick="checking(this);">
```

Comment: But the avascript works fine...

Answer (score 0):

`this` is JavaScript keyword representing the current element, so when `male` clicked it pass checkbox for male and when `female` it pass the female checkbox.